How to make a material for small transparent pebbels
How can I make a material for small transparent rounded pebbles like silica gel pearls?
They look slightly blurry and seem to have a bit of translucency to them.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Maybe simply put the Transmission of the Principled BSDF at 1 and plug a Noise Texture into the Roughness to create some noise on the surface, then play a bit with the needles of a ColorRamp:

